# Unable to have full-screen in Mac's Xmonad

Tags: haskell, installation, xorg, xmonad

I installed the newest X11.
I run the following [command](http://haskell.org/haskellwiki/Xmonad/Using_xmonad_on_Apple_OSX#Installing_GHC) unsuccessfully after sourcing ~/.profile

```
$exec /usr/X11/lib/X11/xinit/xinitrc
```

I get a message

```
Screen is terminating
```

and I do not see any evidence of XMonad.

I run the command the second time, and I get

```
zsh: permission denied: /usr/X11/lib/X11/xinit/xinitrc
Process completed
```

and my  terminal shuts down.

**How can you have the full-screen mode in Mac's Xmonad by xinitrc?**

Comment: Please, close this, since it is no longer relevant. The problem was a combination of different problems.

Comment: other people might run into the same problems, and stumble onto your question when trying to solve them - write up your experience as an answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

exec is a shell built-in. If you insists on using it with sudo, you should do something like:

```
sudo bash -c "exec ...."
```

But that is pretty much pointless, if you use sudo anyway. Just drop the "exec" altogether.

Comment: Yep. Sudo was not the solution to the problem. I left the sudo out. The problem still persists.